# Trying to download a while web page as a single file by converting img src elements with base64

Tags: php, image, base64

I am working on a skill for a little MI project on my website. Currently, this MI has a skill which allows it to clone a URL, however, images wont work without an internet connection, so I am trying to detect all images on the page, convert them to base 64 and embed them directly into the html

```
function getimages($string) {
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
$string2 = preg_replace("~src=[']([^']+)[']~e", '"src=\'" . convert_src("$1") . "\'"', $string);
return $string2;
}

function convert_src($url) {
    $image = file_get_contents($url);
if ($image !== false){
    return 'data:'.mime_content_type($url).';base64,'.base64_encode($image);
}
}
```

If a html page is passed to getimages it should itterate through all src elements, and pass their urls to convert_src which should then download the file in memory, convert to base64, and then replace the original image tag with the new base64 encoded version. This doesn't happen, in my experiments either the whole page is returned blank/empty, the image urls arn't recognized and not processed, or the images dissapear completley.

Please help, I'm struggling here, I'll keep trying on my own in the mean time, but I have very little experience with preg functions.

Answer (score 0):

This solution isn't complete, but it will download and embed (almost) all plain/direct links to image files into a base64 encoded string, replacing the original src attribute.

I'm stuck again tough, now, the code I have, will not process complex urls, such as wikipedia image links, and image links with query data. I believe my method of detectign if data is already base64 encoded, is somehow firing true for some of these complex urls.

Here's what I have so far

```
function getimages($string) {
    $html = $string;
    $html = str_replace("https://", "http://", $html);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
        $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
        if (strpos($src, 'data:image/') === 0 ) {
        $type = pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  
        $data = file_get_contents($src, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        $image->setAttribute("src", $base64);
        }
        $image->removeAttribute("srcset");
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
return $html;
}
```